# How to run android settings activity inside pop-up window?

Tags: android, android-intent, popup, start-activity, android-settings

I want to run some android settings activity like **WIFI_SETTINGS** inside a predefined pop-up window,
I know how to call some android settings activity :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

and know how to make a predefined activity appears as a popup :

```
<activity android:name="my_activity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

and to achieve what I need I tried to declare a pop-up activity and then run the android settings intent using it's `context` but nothing happen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You can't do this. You have no control over how another Activity looks or behaves.

Comment: @DavidWasser a big disappointment :( . and thanks for your help